# What is the good way to change the path for the cache?

Tags: caching, jupyter-notebook, huggingface

I'm trying to use the following code in a jupyter notebook

```
import os
os.environ['HF_HOME'] = "D:/Users/username/.cache/huggingface/"

from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import transformers
import torch
model = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map="auto",
)
```

but when I run it, the cache is always created on the C disk in the default place
C:/Users/username/.cache/huggingface/

I've tried several other means to write the path (with \ in place of /, setting the environment variable in the terminal...), but the default place is always used. My C disk is relatively small and near from full when this happens.

What is the good way to change the path for the cache?

Update: testing the code outside the Jupyter notebook in debug mode, I get the following message, which seems to be a way to the answer:
"UserWarning: `huggingface_hub` cache-system uses symlinks by default to efficiently store duplicated files but your machine does not support them in D:\Users\username.cache\huggingface\hub. Caching files will still work but in a degraded version that might require more space on your disk. This warning can be disabled by setting the `HF_HUB_DISABLE_SYMLINKS_WARNING` environment variable. For more details, see https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/how-to-cache#limitations.
To support symlinks on Windows, you either need to activate Developer Mode or to run Python as an administrator. In order to see activate developer mode, see this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development
warnings.warn(message)"